# Сортировка строк в указанном порядке

Tags: delphi

Как можно сортировать строки в указанном порядке. То есть указываю порядок в котором должны идти строки - **Brend** потом **Nomer_tovara** потом **Year** потом **Garantiya**

**Для примера (Входной файл):**

```
Nomer_tovara: 557436
Brend: VMS
Garantiya: 2343454
Year : 2019

Nomer_tovara: 557436
Brend: ORP
Garantiya: 78788777
Year : 2019
```

**Выходной файл:**

```
Brend: VMS
Nomer_tovara: 557436
Year : 2019
Garantiya: 2343454

Brend: ORP
Nomer_tovara: 557436
Year : 2019
Garantiya: 78788777
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function LineNumber(value: string): Integer;
  begin
    if value = 'Brend' then
      Result := 0
    else if value = 'Nomer_tovara' then
      Result := 1
    else if value = 'Year ' then
      Result := 2
    else if value = 'Garantiya' then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := -1;
  end;

var
  sl: TStringList;
  i, block_line, line_number: Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.NameValueSeparator := ':';
  sl.LoadFromFile('...');
  i := 0;
  block_line := 0;
  while i < sl.Count do
  begin
    if sl.Strings[i] = '' then
    begin
      block_line := i + 1;
      Inc(i);
      Continue;
    end;
    line_number := LineNumber(sl.Names[i]);
    if (line_number > -1) and (line_number <> i - block_line) then
      sl.Exchange(i, block_line + line_number)
    else
      Inc(i);
  end;
  sl.SaveToFile('....');
  sl.Free;
end;
```